# How many significant figures should be used in an answer?

Tags: conventions, error-analysis

For an answer to a problem in significant figures, should the number of significant figures in the answer be based on the term with the least number of significant figures in the prompt?

Just as an example, since this is when I thought of my confusion: Let's say that there is a simple problem where there are two resistors connected in series of $2.766\Omega$ and $2.234\Omega$ and, an $11.2V$ battery, and the answer is the current in Amps. With Ohm's law and adding the resistances, the answer mathematically is

$11.2V=5\Omega\times{I}$

$I = 2.248A$

However, the term with the lowest significant figures is the voltage of the battery with 3 significant figures, so should the answer  be $2.25A$ instead?

Comment: BTW, your example is wrong. 11.2 / 5 = 2.24

Comment: More on [significant figures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+significant+figures).

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but there are some problems with the details, discussed below.

> For an answer to a problem in significant figures

Significant figures in science is like simplifying in mathematics: it is just something that you always do. You do not have specific questions on it (unless you are just learning it).

> should the number of significant figures in the answer be based on the term with the least number of significant figures

Yes.

> $11.2V=5\Omega\times{I}$

It would be better to write the correct number of significant figures:

$$11.2 \text{ V} = 5.000 \text{ }\Omega \times I$$

> $I = 2.248A$

As pointed out by a comment on the question, the correct value (without regard to significant figures) is actually 2.24:

$$I = 2.24 \text{ A}$$

This answer should be rounded to three significant figures; it so happens that it already has the correct number of significant figures!

As an aside, if you click “Edit” on my post, you can see the markup I used for these equations.